# how to get the MS word screen position from the Ribbon control?

Tags: ms-office, ribbon, add-in

I want to get the word position, so that I can position my dialogs relative to the word on the screen in the event handler in the ribbon control

private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)

How to get that? I mean there is no location or Point property which tells the screen coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this same issue. Not sure why, but the RibbonControl class didn't provide a Location property.

It's possible that coordinates are housed somewhere within the COM objects, but I'm no Excel expert.

Anyone else come across this?